# Difference between auto it = v.begin() and int it=v.begin(), where v is a vector<int>

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

It was giving me this error when I used `int it = v.begin()`:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int findFrequency(std::vector<int>, int)’:
prog.cpp:18:32: error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<int>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >}’ to ‘int’ in initialization
     for(int iterator = v.begin();iterator!=v.end();iterator+
```

But it worked fine with `auto it = v.begin()`, why?

Comment: `auto` will figure out what the type needs to be. When you use `auto` it makes `it` a `std::vector::iterator`. `std::vector::begin` returns a `std::vector::iterator`, not an `int`.

Comment: `begin()` returns an iterator, not an int

Comment: `std::vector<int>::begin()` does not return an integral type,  so `int it = v.begin()` will not compile.   `auto it = v.begin()` will work, since it deduces the returned type.

Comment: You may be confusing `v.front()` with `v.begin()`. The former will return the first element of the vector while the later returns an iterator from the start of the vector

Comment: @chatterjee7 plz, If you feel that there is an answer meets your question, aaccept it. If not, provide us with more info about what you have misunderstood.

Answer (score 4):

```
 int it = v.begin()
```

is wrong because the type of what is returned by `v.begin()` is `std::vector<int>::iterator` not `int`

while

```
  auto it = v.begin()
```

deduces the type of the iterator

Answer (score 0):

This is because iterators are not integers. An iterator is a pointer that points to an element in a list like a vector.

An integer is simply a whole number, 1, 2, 3, 4...

You cannot assign an iterator to an integer since they aren't the same. Here is a [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) to read a bit more into iterators

`auto` will simply deduce the type itself so it can figure out that `.begin()` returns an iterator.

Comment: This answer is nearly as good as the one of [asmmo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61220666/7478597) except _An iterator is a pointer_. This sounds literally like a raw pointer. This is an implementation detail (and it might be true on your platform and is on mine AFAIK) but you cannot rely on it.

Comment: @Scheff fair enough. Though judging by the question at hand, it feels appropriate to not dive super deep.

Answer (score 0):

Two points to remember:

- `v.begin()` is an iterator pointing to the first element in your vector `v`. This iterator, with respect to being a vector container of integer type, has a form of `std::vector<int>::iterator`, and not `int`.
- `auto` keyword automatically takes upon the data type from its initializer and assigns that as the data type of the variable declared using it.

---

Possible corrections/alternatives?

- If you were looking to extract the *iterator to the first element* in the vector, then either stick with auto or define the iterator:

```cpp
std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin();
```

- If you were looking to extract the *first element*, then declare it with its data type, which will be an `int` for a vector of `int` type: (as you might have thought of, and as pointed by smac89 as well)

```cpp
int it = v.front();
```

or you can use auto again:

```cpp
auto it = v.front();
```

In this case, the data type for `it` as deduced by auto will be `int`, as thats the type for `v.front()`.